# Join tables in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset, join, datarelation

There's a lot of posts (on this and other sites) about this matter, but every solution I read involves `SQL` queries and I'm not looking for such a solution.

I have three `DataTables` (`vb.NET`) and I want to join them by the first column (which contains a `TimeStamp`).

For instance, if I have three `DataTables` called `TAB01`, `TAB02` and `TAB03` filled like the next ones:

```
          TAB01                          TAB02                          TAB03
TimeStamp             Value1 | TimeStamp             Value2 | TimeStamp             Value3
2019/10/09 09:00:00   0.2334 | 2019/10/09 09:00:00   1.1212 | 2019/10/09 09:00:00   2.1221
2019/10/09 09:01:00   0.1111 | 2019/10/09 09:01:00   4.1211 | 2019/10/09 09:01:00   3.1766
2019/10/09 09:02:00   2.6566 | 2019/10/09 09:02:00   3.2122 | 2019/10/09 09:02:00   0.1322
```

how can I fill a fourth `DataTable` (say `TAB04`) like the next one?

```
                                         TAB04                        
                    | TimeStamp             Value1  Value2  Value3 |
                    | 2019/10/09 09:00:00   0.2334  1.1212  2.1221 |
                    | 2019/10/09 09:01:00   0.1111  4.1211  3.1766 |
                    | 2019/10/09 09:02:00   2.6566  3.2122  0.1322 |
```

The problem seems quite simple (my fist attempt was using collections to save the data from all three tables and then matching the `TimeStamps` to fill the fourth table). However, since I can't guarantee that the `TimeStamps` from the three tables match with each other, the collections technique looks like the worst option.

Is there another way to approach this question?

**UPDATE:**

I found this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660112/how-to-inner-join-two-already-filled-datatables-in-vb-net) that uses a `DataSet` to create a `DataRelation` between to columns of two different tables:

```
'Create DataSet:
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet 
    'Add tables to DataSet:
        ds.Tables.Add(TAB01)
        ds.Tables.Add(TAB02)
    'Create DataRelation:
        Dim dr As DataRelation = New DataRelation("dr", TAB01.Columns(0), TAB02.Columns(0))
    'Add DataRelation to DataSet:
        ds.Relations.Add(dr)
```

So far so good (I understand perfectly the syntax of the code above.
However, as it is mentioned on the link, the command:

```
DGV1.DataSource = ds
```

should fill the `DataGridView` (named `DGV1`) automatically as  the table `TAB04`. Something's missing because this code doesn't fill `DGV1` with anything.
Is this a valid method? If so, what am I missing? Why `DGV1`'s still empty?

Comment: is a datagrid an option? cause it's not sql related

Comment: @Devcon, this is for a program to run on a background scenario. It practically doesn't have any user design interface. So I'm not so much interested in inserting a datagrid on the form. Can you tell me how a datagrid is a good approach?

Comment: you can use a datagridview without adding it to design: `Dim dgv As New DataGridView`

Comment: Ok! You're right. But how I join the three tables on a datagrid?

Comment: Does [LINQ join two DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760681/linq-join-two-datatables) help?

Comment: Not really! I don't know how to work with it...

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1232129.aspx?Combining+2+datatables+into+1+datatable+based+on+a+common+field+ create a dataset, add the tables, add the dataset relation, add the column to the second table. Try it

Comment: Thanks for the link @Devcon. I think I got it!

Comment: If data always looks like that, you could simply add rows in for x to row.count loop where datatable4.rows.add(dt1(col,row).value,dt1..,dt2..,dt3..)