# How to join two or more DataTables together to display in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to find the correct way to join two datatables, or more, into a single datatable and use it as the datasource for a DataGridView.  I have read through all sort of examples and posts, but nothing I've tried seems to be working.  I'm sure I'm missing something, but not sure what.

I have three tables: dt_Record (25 columns), dt_ENDP (35 columns) and dt_ITSM (12 columns) and each of these come from **different database servers**.  Because I'm not admin of these servers, I cannot join them in any way.  For now I'm just trying to get the first two tables to join so I have a basis of HOW to do it.  This joined table/DGV will be used for a report where the user can select which columns they want visible and exported to Excel.

Here is what I have tried per a [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23672745/9105815):

```
Private Sub Open_Report(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PrintToolStripButton.Click
    Try
        ds_Record = New DataSet
        ds_Record.Tables.Add(dt_Record)
        ds_Record.Tables.Add(dt_ENDP)
        Dim dr As DataRelation = New DataRelation("ENDP", ds_Record.Tables(0).Columns("Endpoint_Tag"), ds_Record.Tables(1).Columns("Computer_Name"))
        ds_Record.Relations.Add(dr)

        frmIT_Report.ShowDialog()

    Catch ex As Exception
        CustExErrorMsg(Me.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message)
    Finally
        If Not IsNothing(ds_Record) Then ds_Record.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

The other form that is opening, and has the DGV, has the following code:

```
Private Sub frmIT_Report_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        With dgvResults
            .RowHeadersWidth = 12
            .DataSource = frmIT_Equip.ds_Record.Tables(0)
        End With
        
        txtResults.Text = CStr(dgvResults.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.None))
        
    Catch ex As Exception
        CustExErrorMsg(Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

When the form opens, the DGV is only filled with the data from the dt_Records table, and nothing from the second table.  OK, fine.  Per another solution I found, I added the following, after adding the relation to the dataset, to see if that would bring in the data from the second table:

```
For Each row As DataRow In ds_Record.Tables(0).Rows
    Row.GetChildRows(dr)
Next
```

Nope, that still only produces the first table.  So then I found another solution that required adding a column at the end of the first table:

```
ds_Record.Tables(0).Columns.Add("Build_Date", GetType(String), "Parent.Build_Date")
```

But that produces an error of "Cannot find relation 0"  So then I went out on a limb with another solution using LINQ to join the tables: (I am not very familiar with LINQ, yet.)

```
Dim qry = From t1 In ds_Record.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() Join
    t2 In ds_Record.Tables(1).AsEnumerable On
    t1.Item("Endpoint_Tag") Equals t2.Item("Computer_Name")
          Select New With {
                Key .A = t1.Field(Of String)("Endpoint_Tag"),
                .B = t1.Field(Of Integer)("Class_ID"),
                .C = t2.Field(Of String)("Computer_Name"),
                .D = t2.Field(Of String)("Build_Date")}

Dim dt As New DataTable
For Each item In qry.ToList
    dt.Rows.Add(item.A, item.B, item.C, item.D)
Next
ds_Record.Tables.Add(dt)
```

But that produces error "Specified Cast in not allowed"  But even if that did work, or the precious code, I don't want to have to cast almost 70 columns in my code - that just seem ludicrous.

On the surface this seems like it should be easy to solve.  So what am I missing?

Comment: Primarily that using `DataTables` instead of anonymous or defined classes doesn't cleanly interoperate with modern .Net classes like DGV. OTOH, classes don't make it easy to consolidate lots of properties (columns) either. Also, 70 columns is of questionable value in a data  grid anyway.

Comment: @NetMage  I won't disagree that 70 columns is ridiculous for a DGV.  However, the user(s) want to see the data they would be exporting before taking that action.  And because the "organization" did a horrible job of SQL data management, there is data all over the servers in all sorts of tables.  I'm just trying to piece it altogether for my own use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method you can use to convert LINQ results from a join into a new `DataTable`. It uses the following extension methods:

```
Module QueryExt
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function AsSingleton(Of T As New)(item As T) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Return New T() { item }
    End Function

    ' ***
    ' *** Type Extensions
    ' ***
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> 
    Public Function GetPropertiesOrFields(t As Type, Optional bf As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance) As List(Of MemberInfo)
        Return t.GetMembers(bf).Where(Function(mi) (mi.MemberType = MemberTypes.Field) Or (mi.MemberType = MemberTypes.Property)).ToList()
    End Function

    ' ***
    ' *** MemberInfo Extensions
    ' ***
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function GetMemberType(member As MemberInfo) As Type
        If Typeof member Is FieldInfo Then
            Dim mfi As FieldInfo = member
            Return mfi.FieldType
        ElseIf Typeof member Is PropertyInfo Then
            Dim mpi As PropertyInfo = member
            Return mpi.PropertyType
        ElseIf Typeof member Is EventInfo Then
            Dim mei As EventInfo = member
            Return mei.EventHandlerType
        Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be if type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or EventInfo", Nameof(member))
        End If
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> 
    Public Function GetValue(member As MemberInfo, srcObject As Object) As Object
        If Typeof member Is FieldInfo Then
            Dim mfi As FieldInfo = member
            Return mfi.GetValue(srcObject)
        ElseIf Typeof member Is PropertyInfo Then
            Dim mpi As PropertyInfo = member
            Return mpi.GetValue(srcObject)
        ElseIf Typeof member Is MethodInfo Then
            Dim mi As MethodInfo = member
            Return mi.Invoke(srcObject, Nothing)
        Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or MethodInfo", Nameof(member))
        End If
    End Function
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> 
    Public Function GetValue(Of T)(member As MemberInfo, srcObject As Object) As T
        Return DirectCast(member.GetValue(srcObject), T)
    End Function

    ' ***
    ' *** DataTable Extensions
    ' ***
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> 
    Public Function DataColumns(aTable As DataTable) As IEnumerable(Of DataColumn)
        Return aTable.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)()
    End Function
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> 
    Public Function ColumnNames(aTable As DataTable) As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Return aTable.DataColumns().Select(Function(dc) dc.ColumnName)
    End Function

    ' Create new DataTable from LINQ join results on DataTable
    ' Expect T to be anonymous object of form new { [DataRow or other] d1, [DataRow or other] d2, ... }
    ' result flattens each object to DataRow with Fields from each dx or a new Field named after dx
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> 
    Public Function FlattenToDataTable(Of T)(items As IEnumerable(Of T)) As DataTable
        Dim res = New DataTable()
        If (items.Any()) Then
            Dim firstRow = items.First()
            Dim memberInfos = GetType(T).GetPropertiesOrFields()
            Dim allDC = memberInfos.SelectMany(Function(mi) If(mi.GetMemberType() = GetType(DataRow), mi.GetValue(Of DataRow)(firstRow).Table.DataColumns(), New DataColumn(mi.Name, mi.GetMemberType()).AsSingleton()))

            For Each dc In allDC
                Dim newColumnName = dc.ColumnName
                If res.ColumnNames().Contains(newColumnName) Then
                    Dim suffixNumber = 1
                    While res.ColumnNames().Contains($"{newColumnName}.{suffixNumber}")
                        suffixNumber += 1
                    End While
                    newColumnName = $"{newColumnName}.{suffixNumber}"
                End If
                res.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(newColumnName, dc.DataType))
            Next

            For Each item In items
                res.Rows.Add(memberInfos.SelectMany(Function(mi) If(mi.GetMemberType() = GetType(DataRow), mi.GetValue(Of DataRow)(item).ItemArray, (New Object() { mi.GetValue(item) }).ToArray())))
            Next
        End If
        Return res
    End Function
    
End Module
```

With this extension method, you can use LINQ as follows:

```
Dim qry = From t1 In ds_Record.Tables(0).AsEnumerable()
          Join t2 In ds_Record.Tables(1).AsEnumerable On t1.Item("Endpoint_Tag") Equals t2.Item("Computer_Name")
          Select New With { t1, t2 }
Dim dt = qry.FlattenToDataTable()
```

Comment: I got the extension added to my project, and updated the LINQ query to match.  However, I'm getting the following error:  `"Unable to cast object of type '<SelectManyIterator>d__17``2[System.Reflection.MemberInfo,System.Object]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>d__17``2[System.Reflection.MemberInfo,System.Object]> in ID_IT_Asset Column.  Expected type is Int32."` on the following line:  `res.Rows.Add(memberInfos.SelectMany(Function(mi)...`  Not enough room to add the whole line, but that should tell you.

Comment: I was able to get it to work, slightly.  I changed the first table (dt_Records) to my third table (dt_ITSM). The DGV "fills," but the only value it has is `"System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>d__17'2[System.Reflection.MemberInfo,System.Object]"` repeated in the first column.  It does look like all the headers are getting loaded for both tables.  I'm going to keep playing around with it to see if I can work out the issue.  If you happen to figure it out, please let me know.

Comment: May be an issue with my translation to VB from the original C#... I'll see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get something worked out to "join" my three tables into a single DataTable.  Granted it's probably not the most efficient, but it does work.

The code first creates a clone and copy of the "parent" DataTable.  It then loops through the columns of each "child" DataTable and adds those columns.  (I had to add a prefix for each table because the tables had identical names.)

It then loops through the rows of the new DataTable and uses a SELECT statement to capture the data and place it in it's appropriate column.

I'm sure this could get wrapped up into a function as well.

```
    Private Sub Open_Report(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PrintToolStripButton.Click
    Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt = dt_Record.Clone
        dt = dt_Record.Copy

        '** ITSM
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt_ITSM.Columns
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ITSM_" + col.ColumnName, col.DataType))
        Next
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim val As DataRow = dt_ITSM.Select("asset_tag = '" + row.Item("Endpoint_Tag").ToString + "'").FirstOrDefault
            If Not val Is Nothing Then
                For Each col As DataColumn In val.Table.Columns
                    row("ITSM_" + col.ColumnName) = val.Item(col.ColumnName)
                Next
            End If
        Next

        '** Endpoint
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt_ENDP.Columns
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ENDP_" + col.ColumnName, col.DataType))
        Next
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim val As DataRow = dt_ENDP.Select("Computer_Name = '" + row.Item("Endpoint_Tag").ToString + "'").FirstOrDefault
            If Not val Is Nothing Then
                For Each col As DataColumn In val.Table.Columns
                    row("ENDP_" + col.ColumnName) = val.Item(col.ColumnName)
                Next
            End If
        Next

        ds_Record = New DataSet
        ds_Record.Tables.Add(dt)

        frmIT_Report.ShowDialog()

    Catch ex As Exception
        CustExErrorMsg(Me.Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message)
    Finally
        If Not IsNothing(ds_Record) Then ds_Record.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```