# How do you combine two datatable and then display it in one gridview in vb?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datatable, merge

this is the code for merging the two datatable : dt_merged.Merge(dt)

Answer (score 0):

In C# is: (Just convert to VB Syntax)

```
dt1 = new DataTable();
dt2 = new DataTable();
dt1.Merge(dt2);

grid.DataSource = dt1;
```

> Replace the dt1 and dt2 by loading from your database.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkk7s5zk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This might be duplicated, you can check in this link: 
[Merging 2 data tables in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262383/merging-2-data-tables-in-vb-net)

Comment: i tried this but this error comes up Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined. i cant seem to figure out how to combine both

Comment: @ANNE try this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/255064/Both-DataSource-and-DataSourceID-are-defined-on-Gr

Comment: @ANNE the link above has a solution for you problem with examples.